# google mock - how to say "function must be called ONCE with a certain parameter but ok to be called many times with different parameters"?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I need to detect that a given function has been called exactly ONCE with a certain set of arguments.

`EXPECT_CALL(Mock_Obj, func("abc")).Times(1)`

but it's ok for that function to be called with different arguments any number of times.

How do I express that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GoogleMock: how to expect precisely one call with a certain argument, and see diagnostic on failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26060835/googlemock-how-to-expect-precisely-one-call-with-a-certain-argument-and-see-di)

Comment: Related, but definitely *not* a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44034633/google-mock-can-i-call-expect-call-multiple-times-on-same-mock-object/60905880#60905880

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Google Mock, later expectations override earlier ones (more details in the [docs](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#performing-different-actions-based-on-the-arguments)), so you can write this:

```
EXPECT_CALL(Mock_Obj, func(_)).Times(AnyNumber());
EXPECT_CALL(Mock_Obj, func("abc")).Times(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little more info. Do [like VladLosev said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44252148/4561887). Put the default (most generic because it allows *any* argument with the `_` character) case *first* and the more specific cases *after*, to override the default case if they match first. I say that the latter `EXPECT_CALL()`s may match *first* because gmock does a *reverse* search for matches, meaning it tries to match the *last* `EXPECT_CALL()` *first*, then it moves its way upwards, stopping and exiting this process at the *first* match it finds for the call, in this reverse order.

```
EXPECT_CALL(Mock_Obj, func(_)).Times(AnyNumber());
EXPECT_CALL(Mock_Obj, func("abc")).Times(1);
EXPECT_CALL(Mock_Obj, func("def")).Times(1);
EXPECT_CALL(Mock_Obj, func("cab")).Times(1);
EXPECT_CALL(Mock_Obj, func("bac")).Times(1);
```

From the ["gMock for Dummies {#GMockForDummies}" guide](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_for_dummies.md#using-multiple-expectations-multiexpectations):

> ### Using Multiple Expectations {#MultiExpectations}
>
> So far we've only shown examples where you have a single expectation. More
> realistically, you'll specify expectations on multiple mock methods which may be
> from multiple mock objects.
>
> By default, when a mock method is invoked, gMock will search the expectations in
> the **reverse order** they are defined, and stop when an active expectation that
> matches the arguments is found (you can think of it as "newer rules override
> older ones."). If the matching expectation cannot take any more calls, you will
> get an upper-bound-violated failure. Here's an example:
>
> ```cpp
> using ::testing::_;
> ...
> EXPECT_CALL(turtle, Forward(_));  // #1
> EXPECT_CALL(turtle, Forward(10))  // #2
>     .Times(2);
> ```
>
> If `Forward(10)` is called three times in a row, the third time it will be an
> error, as the last matching expectation (#2) has been saturated. If, however,
> the third `Forward(10)` call is replaced by `Forward(20)`, then it would be OK,
> as now #1 will be the matching expectation.
>
> **Note:** Why does gMock search for a match in the *reverse* order of the
> expectations? The reason is that this allows a user to set up the default
> expectations in a mock object's constructor or the test fixture's set-up phase
> and then customize the mock by writing more specific expectations in the test
> body. So, if you have two expectations on the same method, you want to put the
> one with more specific matchers **after** the other, or the more specific rule
> would be shadowed by the more general one that comes after it.
>
> **Tip:** It is very common to start with a catch-all expectation for a method
> and `Times(AnyNumber())` (omitting arguments, or with `_` for all arguments, if
> overloaded). This makes any calls to the method expected. This is not necessary
> for methods that are not mentioned at all (these are "uninteresting"), but is
> useful for methods that have some expectations, but for which other calls are
> ok. See
> Understanding Uninteresting vs Unexpected Calls.

## Related:

1. [google mock - can I call EXPECT_CALL multiple times on same mock object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44034633/google-mock-can-i-call-expect-call-multiple-times-on-same-mock-object/60905880#60905880)